# outputting json to string

Tags: ruby, json, string

I've been teaching myself ruby but now I have encountered a problem I keep getting a error:

```
mesureitcurrentv.rb:9:in `[]': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)
from mesureitcurrentv.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

and i cant seem to fix the code.

Json:

```
[{"sensor":{"x":"","sensor_id":"0","sensor_title":"sensor 0","sensor_clamp":"0","position_id":"1","position_time":"2013-10-13 17:38:39","position_description":"start position","position_sensor":"0","measure_history":"365","measure_currency":"Pound","measure_sensor":"0","measure_range":"","measure_timeframe":"0","measure_timezone":"GMT0","measure_timezone_diff":"0","measure_type":"0","measure_pvoutput_id":"0","measure_pvoutput_api":"","positions":{"1":{"position":"1","time":"2013-10-13 17:38:39","description":"start position"}}},"tmpr":"20.5","watt":"703","daily":"13.86 Kwh<br \/>2.13","hourly":"0.47 Kwh<br \/>0.07","weekly":"112.748 Kwh<br \/>17.35","monthly":"506.063 Kwh<br \/>77.88"}]
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'net/http'
require 'json'


http = Net::HTTP.new("192.168.1.11")
response=http.request(Net::HTTP::Get.new("/php/measureit_functions.php?do=summary_start"))
pjson = JSON[response.body]
p pjson["sensor"]["watt"]
```

Comment: Maybe `pjson[0]["sensor"]["watt"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A previous answer states your TypeError is coming from the line

```
pjson = JSON[response.body]
```

This is not the case; it is coming from

```
p pjson["sensor"]["watt"].
```

`JSON[x]` and `JSON.parse(x)` are interchangeable.

The TypeError is thrown because pjson is an array, not a hash, and only accepts integer positions (e.g. `pjson[0]`).  `pjson` is an array because while the raw json text has only one top-level hash object, it's nested in an array (the initial "[").

Additionally, as noted by Michael's answer, `"watt"` is not a subkey of `"sensor"` -- it's a key in the top-level hash.  So what you want is `pjson[0]` to get your hash object, and then `pjson[0]["watt"]` to get the value of `"watt"` (in this case, "703").

```
    pjson[0]['watt']
    => "703"
```

Comment: Never knew `JSON#[]` existed as a method, but [there it is in the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-5B-5D)

Comment: Sorry tested this during the day in school for got to get round to marking a answer

Answer (score 3):

For clarity, I would recommend using [`JSON.parse`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse) instead of [the `[]` operator method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-5B-5D).

```
pjson = JSON.parse response.body
```

The key `watt` is not a subkey of `sensor`.  It is a subkey of the parent array element.  The outer `[]` implies an array, and having at least one numeric key.

So directly, you may retrieve `watt` via:

```
# watt is a key of the array element [0]
pjson[0]['watt']
=> "703"
```

But more robustly, you could retrieve all of them paired with their `sensor_id`s via, if you ever expect to have more than one array element returned:

```
pjson.map { |s| [s['sensor']['sensor_id'], s['watt']] }
```

Which will return an array of arrays like

```
[["0", "703"]]
```

Or with the `sensor_title`:

```
pjson.map { |s| [s['sensor']['sensor_title'], s['watt']] }
=> [["sensor 0", "703"]]
```